# Get interface name into linux shell script variable

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to store an interface name into a variable in linux shell script. I found a solution to do this via "grep" command and the IP-Address. My problem is that my interface doesn't have an IP-Address at this moment.

The interface name always begins with "enx" and the MAC-Address like "enxb2240be99fc3" while the MAC-Address can change every reboot.

Is there a solution to get this interface name into a shell script variable?

Comment: Please be more specific.. Give example inputs, expected outputs etc.

Comment: Ok, for example: i get 3 interface names with"ls /sys/class/net". One of those names is "enxb2240be99fc3" (MAC-Address changes every reboot). I only want this one extracted into a variable in shell script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
iname=$(ip -o link show | sed -rn '/^[0-9]+: en/{s/.: ([^:]*):.*/\1/p}')
```

save the interface name to variable `iname`

Answer (score 1):

ip addr show | awk '/inet.*brd/{print $NF}'

this is also works,check it...

Answer (score 1):

```
iname=$(ls /sys/class/net | grep -i enx)
echo $iname
```